# Load two DLLs with different versions

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, .net-assembly

I am developing a project in which I have to create a new feature.

Now I am facing a problem that there is a DLL reference in a project with old version and for developing the feature I need a new dll with new version so it's not possible to use both DLLs in the same project but both DLLs are required to run the features.

What is the best technique to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Create 2 shared assemblies and put it in GAC.
check this link, this will solve your problem.

http://geekswithblogs.net/narent/archive/2008/11/11/126940.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for your problem is the global assembly cache (gac)

use the tool gacutil.exe and add both of your assemblys to the gac. It works great for using different versions of on dll-file

try to google for it, gac will help you ;)